# Google Talk Video Chat

Tags: video, alternative, google-talk, instant-messaging

There are no video chat plugins supplied by Google for Ubuntu. They are availabe just for PC and Mac. Are there any alternatives?

UPDATE:
Google has launched official video chat plugin for Linux

http://www.google.com/chat/video

http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/use-linux-now-you-can-video-chat-too.html

Comment: You asked and they gave :) video/audio chat is now available for ubuntu and debian based distros. http://gmail.com/videochat

Comment: Yes indeed. Maybe you should start asking more things @shubhkarman, we'd been waiting for 4 years for that to happen ;-)

Comment: Can you ask when Wave will be fully open-sourced please?

Comment: @Raphink Maybe we really should..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Google video can now be used in Linux. [gmailblog](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/use-linux-now-you-can-video-chat-too.html)
You can download it [here](http://www.google.com/chat/video).

Comment: I first tried installing using KPackageKit, but got an error. Worked okay with dpkg. Got video, but not my mic yet

Answer (score 18):

The default IM application in Ubuntu, [Empathy](http://live.gnome.org/Empathy), supports Google Talk voice and video out of the box.

In order to use it, right click on the contact and select either "Audio Call" or "Video Call". 
Users that have audio capability will have a microphone next to their name in the contact list, and a little webcam if they have video support.

Google also now supports Linux officially in their client, which you can download from [here](http://www.google.com/chat/video).

Answer (score 4):

Another popular IM application, [pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/), supports Google Talk voice/video.

It is available from the Ubuntu Software Centre.

Answer (score 1):

I use pidgin for voice chat. You have to enable voice/video plugin of pidgin. The official google voice chat is now available for linux as well

Answer (score 0):

A painless way to install it

In a terminal

```
wget http://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-talkplugin_current_i386.deb && sudo dpkg -i google-talkplugin_current_i386.deb
```

Comment: This works only for 32-bit Ubuntu installations, not 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use gtalk made for chrome os. It can be used in any linux supporting google chrome using this tutorial.
http://tutafuta.com/2011/05/25/how-to-use-gtalk-on-linux-or-mac/
you can use this handy trick to do all you can do with google talk, audio/video chatting