# Google Voice and Video: Video is not supported on this OS

Tags: google-chrome, google-talk

Im running the latest release version (5.0.372.127) of chrome on karmic koala x86. I just installed *[Google Voice and Video](http://www.google.com/chat/video/download.html)* chrome plugin with out problems but if I try to start a video call then I get this message (in the chat window).

> Video is not supported on this OS.
>   Learn more...

The *learn more...* is static text i.e. no link so thats not much use. A quick google shows that ubuntu does support this feature, theres even a thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2522/google-talk-video-chat-on-ubuntu).

Any ideas?

---

Sorry if Iv'e omitted any crucial information, let me know and Ill update the question ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use something like [Empathy](http://live.gnome.org/Empathy) (`sudo apt-get install empathy` in the command line or via `Applications -> Ubuntu Software Center`) or [Pidgin](http://pidgin.im/) (`sudo apt-get install pidgin` in the command line or via `Applications -> Ubuntu Software Center`) which are both IM application for the desktop that support a wide variety of protocols (Google Voice and Video included) in order to connect to the Google Talk servers and other gTalk user.

Empathy is the default IM client for Ubuntu and should already be installed on versions 10.04 and higher.

It appears you can download install the Linux plugin for Google Chat [here](http://www.google.com/chat/video/download.html) ensuring you select the proper architecture. I was unable to test it, but the download and installation on 10.04 was clean.

Comment: Empathy is already installed (by default), the plugin you linked to is the one Im having problems with (32bit .deb)

Answer (score 0):

By installing that .deb, it seems to work in chromium 5.0.375.125 on Ubuntu 10.04. I haven't actually made a call but it pops up a little window allowing you to dial a number.

This plugin is a browser plugin that requires you to go into the gmail web interface to use it.

If Empathy has Google voice and video support as @Marco Ceppi says, then it would be better to use that.

Comment: I can confirm that both audio and video worked for me on Ubuntu 10.04 using the latest stable Google Chrome.

Comment: Hmmm Im on 9.10 and neither Empathy or the browser plugin are working.

Comment: I just tried pidgin and have the same problem, -i.e. it works for IM but not for video with google talk.

Comment: What version of Empathy do you have? You can find this from Help -> About in Empathy.

Comment: Empathy version 2.28.1